# Topic-like concurrent queue in plain Java

Tags: java, concurrency, queue

Before I reinvent the wheel, is there a topic-like concurrent queue in plain Java? I have the following requirements:

- Multiple readers/consumers
- Multiple writers/producers
- Every message must be consumed by every (active) consumer
- After every consumer reads a message it should become garbage (i.e. no more references)
- Writing to the queue should not be O(N) to the number of consumers
- Concurrent, preferably non-blocking
- Not JMS based: it's for a much lighter/embeddable environment

That's pretty much everything I need. Any pointers?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "plain Java", but EventBus (http://eventbus.org/) might be something to check out.

Comment: Thanks, I checked EventBus. It's a nice project but not entirely adequate to my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are talking about multiplexing, and no there isn't something in the standard lib but it is pretty simple to create one. Presuming that your clients aren't interested in messages published before they subscribe then you need a pool of queues for each consumer and publication simply offers the item to each queue:

```
public class Multiplexer<M> {
  private final List<BlockingQueue<M>> consumers 
    = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<BlockingQueue<M>>();

  public void publish(M msg) {
    for (BlockingQueue<M> q : consumers) {
      q.offer(msg);
    }
  }

  public void addConsumer(BlockingQueue<M> consumer) {
    consumers.add(consumer);
  }
}
```

This version allows consumers to use whatever blocking queue implementation they might want. You could obviously provide a standard implementation and a nice interface for the client if you want.

Comment: This works, assuming you are ok with the consumers actually blocking on the `offer` call. It's the same advice for any 'listener' pattern - the listeners should perform their action as fast as possible, which may mean another thread should do the work. If this is a common scenario, maybe the multiplexer should create a thread per consumer (or some sort of thread pool) to manage sending the messages.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution increases the time to publish linearly with the consumers. I edited the post to make this clear.

Comment: @AngerClown any BlockingQueue implementation that blocks on `offer(e)` is fundamentally broken. As to listener action and threads, consumers poll/take from the queue when they want.

Comment: @daniel-yokomizo why do you need constant time offer/publish? how many consumers do you have?

Comment: I'm writing a multicast actor system, so potentially thousands.

Comment: @daniel-yokomizo that really doesn't sound like much (the insert cost is very low, I thought you might mean millions). I'd probably want to test the performance before trying to optimise for insert. I had a go at a multi-view queue, but the increase in complexity of the design is just enormous and isn't really justified. Probably the simplest option if you really don't want the publisher to pay the insert cost is to drop a job on an Executor and make publishing asynchronous.

Comment: I ended up writing two implementations specialized to that set of requirements and one based on your suggestion. Both scale better than this one, mostly because I managed to avoid most contention between subscribers and publishers and also because we use much less memory.

Answer (score 0):

the 3rd condition is not in plain java but you can use a [nonblocking linked queue](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/michael/PODC96.html) with a separate head for each consumer (you can rely on GC to collect the unreferenced nodes)

Comment: Very interesting paper. I'll implement it to compare with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest strategy is to pass a message to every consumer, I wouldn't have so many consumer that the number of consumers is important.  You can add messages to dozens of consumers in a few micro-seconds.

One way to avoid this is to have a circular ring buffer with many readers.  This is tricky to implement and means the consumers will be limited in the number of sources of message they can have.

Answer (score 0):

Have just one pseudo-consumer and let the real consumers register with the pseudo-consumer. When a producer sends a message, the pseudo consumer wakes up and consumes the message. On consuming the message, the pseudo-consumer creates a separate `Runnable` for each real consumer registered with it and executes them on a thread-pool.